# Query - If more than one record ID# (non primary key) matches, use later date or larger primary key

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I built a MS Access Database that takes a survey to create a custom report.  The survey application that was used does not give us the reports we need. I usually grab the data (excel) and import it in access and build report the way we need them.

For this first time, we have people redoing the survey because they are updating something or they forgot to add something.  I need to be able to grab the most recent surveys data so we don't get a duplicate when we run the report.  (My main report is composed of several subreports. Some subreports will not visible if null, and any questions not answered are hidden and shrinked to prevent bulky reports with unnecessary whitespace.)

```
 record ID (PK) |  FName   |  LName   | IDNum   | Completed
     1          |  Bob     |  Smith   |  57     | 3/31/2013 5:00pm
     2          |  Bob     |  Smith   |  57     | 3/31/2013 7:00pm
```

I want record ID 2 or the one that was completed at 7pm.

The queries and reports are already completed so i have been trying to find a way to add a line of code in the criteria line of my query to grab the most recent record if the IDnum matches with more than one record.

I have been trying to find the best way to do it for the past several hours.  I don't think that having my table be modified to 'table without duplicates' as after the database is complete, someone less technical will be using it. All they are going to do is import a new excel file to overwrite the table and the queries do everything to build the report.  I don't want to manually delete the duplicate records either.

I know I need to do something along the lines with

```
 IIF(count(IDNum)>1, *something, *something)
```

*I get stuck on the true and false part. How do i tell access that it needs to check within the table again to find the record with the larger primary key?

I thought this was going to be easy but i guess i was wrong. lol

I am fairly new at MS Access so I know I am not using the full potential and i might be going at this at the wrong angle.  Any advice would be appreciated greatly.
I'm a student going into Info Systems, so i would really like to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the query you are looking for is

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM YourTable t1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT IDNum, MAX(Completed) AS MaxOfCompleted 
     FROM YourTable GROUP BY IDNum
    ) t2
ON t1.IDNum = t2.IDNum AND t1.Completed = t2.MaxOfCompleted;
```

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. Didn't realize I could designate my table like that in access.  Makes sense as it is SQL. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an if function it should be iif not iff.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a correlated subquery, such as the following:

```
SELECT
Data.RecordID
, Data.FName
, Data.LName
, Data.IDNum
, Data.Completed

FROM
Data

WHERE
Data.Completed IN

(
SELECT TOP 1
DataSQ.Completed
FROM
Data as DataSQ

WHERE
DataSQ.IDNum = Data.IDNum

GROUP BY
DataSQ.Completed

ORDER BY
DataSQ.Completed DESC
)

GROUP BY
Data.RecordID
, Data.FName
, Data.LName
, Data.IDNum
, Data.Completed

;
```

**Explanation**

Instead of using a function such as Max or IIF, you can embed another SELECT query within the WHERE clause of your main query. The nested query is used to determine the most recent Completed date for every IDNum. Unlike selecting the most recent survey directly from your table with SELECT TOP 1 + ORDER BY, which would only return one record, the WHERE clause in your nested query refers back to the main query and produces a result for each IDNum. This is known as the Top N per Group pattern, and I've found it to be very useful. Note that in the nested query you will need to use a table name alias so that Access will be able to differentiate between the two queries.

Also, I'd generally recommend against trying to use a table PK to perform sorts. There are many cases when the PK order value will not be a good indicator of the values of related fields.

This code worked when tested on dummy data - best of luck!